# ¿Como puedo agregar un gradiente horizontal en CSS?

Tags: css

Estoy intentando agregar un gradiente a un `div` y lo quiero horizontal

```
article:nth-of-type(1){
 background:linear-gradient(#0f0f0f80,#DDD);
 opacity:1;
 border:0px solid #DDD;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estudia este código:

```
background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(104,104,231,1) 51%);
```

90deg es para hacelo horizontal
el rgba es el rgb con la opacidad (4º termino)
y finalmente el % es el punto de transición (51% es la mitad de la linea horizontal)

Answer (score 3):

Añadiendo el parámetro `to right` a `linear-gradient` podrías hacer que el conjunto de colores se apliquen de izquierda a derecha.

```css
.gradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```